# The meaning of side-effect in Clojure

Tags: clojure, side-effects

I was thinking on the meaning of side-effect in Clojure. What exactly is a side-effect in Clojure? Could any one explain this with an example?

Comment: This is clear enough, though it may be too broad. It is certainly not specific to Clojure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A side effect in any programming language would be everything that is done which does not have a direct correlation between supplied arguments and the returned result.

```
(+ 3 4)      ; ==> 7 (result is always a mapping between arguments and result. It will always be 7 no matte rhow many times you do it. 
(rand-int 4) ; ==> 0,1,2, or 3. You have no idea what it will produce next.
```

The first expression is functional. You can make a lookup table of all the different two values with it's result and you wouldn't know the difference.

The second might give different result for the same argument. The computation must be based on something else, like internal state, and not the argument alone. It has side effects.

Typical side effects used in programs are I/O and object mutation.

Comment: How about "In any programming language, a side effect *of a function* is anything that it does except return a result."?

Comment: @Thumbnail It's true fro everything that has arguments and a return value, not only functions. Eg. Java String **class** is functional and every of it's **methods** are functional as well. The reason is that every String object does not supply any method that mutates it's internal state. Also Scheme doesn't have functions but procedures. It's the same as function of course, but you won't see many answers for Scheme questions using the term function.

Comment: so is that right to say the first expression is a pure function, while the 2nd has side effects? and why `println` is known also to have side effects (i read it somewhere...)

Comment: Your answer, your choice. In my view, a Java method is a function attached to a class and Scheme's procedure is just another name for a function.

Comment: @teymuri No.  I only showed application. `+` is a pure function and `rand-int` (and `println`) isn't.

Comment: i have written this for finding a prim number: `(defn prime? [n]
  (loop [k 2]
    (cond
     (< k n) (if (not= 0 (mod n k))
               (recur (inc k))
               (println n "is not a prim number"))
     :else (println n "is a prim number"))))
` Does it have side effects only because of the `println` or there are other factors which have side effects in it, and is it a correct "functional" way to write it like this?

Comment: @teymuru yes. It prints and it is a side effect. I addition it returns `nil` for all arguments so it's hardly a predicate.